# Find location last object on PDF page using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

How can I find the location and the height of the last object on a PDF page?  There is no footer.  I'm wanting to stamp a template below the last item.  Not in the footer but directly below the last line of text.  The amount of text may vary so I need to calculate if there is enough room at the bottom of the page to insert my template.

Thanks for any help,
Aaron

Comment: To determine where the text on the given page ends, have a look at the iText in Action, 2nd edition example [ShowTextMargins](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=280) which parses a PDF and adds a rectangle showing the text margin.

Comment: How do I show this question has been answered in the comments?

Comment: I created an actual answer with the contents of my comment. You now can accept that answer as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine where text and (bitmap) images on a given page end, have a look at the iText in Action, 2nd edition example [ShowTextMargins](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=280) which parses a PDF and adds a rectangle showing the text and (bitmap) images margin.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    TextMarginFinder finder;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        finder = parser.processContent(i, new TextMarginFinder());
        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(i);
        cb.rectangle(finder.getLlx(), finder.getLly(),
            finder.getWidth(), finder.getHeight());
        cb.stroke();
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

Be aware, though, that this mechanism *ignores vector graphics* (often also used for underlining text, colored backgrounds, and decorative separating lines) because the underlying iText parser package still (as of iText version 5.4.5) ignores them.

**Update**: As of version 5.5.6 iText extends the parser package to also include vector graphics parsing. This allows for an extension of the original `TextMarginFinder` class implementing the new `ExtRenderListener` methods as presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20212172/1729265) resulting in an analogous class [`MarginFinder`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/MarginFinder.java) which does not only consider text but also other kind of content, e.g. bitmap images and vector graphics.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you have a footer on the page? i.e. I want to insert some text between the last bit of text and the footer, but TextMarginFinder just finds the footer.

Comment: @Rowan *Is there a way to do this if you have a footer on the page?* - I have two options on my mind for that: **1** If you *know* about your documents that the footer (if a document has any) always is below a certain **y** coordinate and content always is above it, then you can filter the `TextMarginFinder` input to only take content above that line into account. Alternatively, **2** you can use the `FreeSpaceFinder[Ext]` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503289/1729265) to find sufficiently large patches of empty space on a page, in your case it should be as wide as the page.