# How can I can insert an image or stamp on a pdf where there is free space available like a density scanner

Tags: java, itext

I have a pdf file where-in I am adding a stamp to all it's pages.

But, the problem is, the stamp is added to the upper-left corner of each page. If, the page has text in that part, the stamp appears on the text.

My question is, is there any method by which I can read each page and if there is no text in that part add the stamp else search for nearest available free space, just like what a density scanner does?

I am using IText and Java 1.7.

The free space fider class and the distance calculation function are the same that is there in the accepted answer.

Following is the edited code I am using:

```
    // The resulting PDF file
    String RESULT = "K:\\DCIN_TER\\DCIN_EPU2\\CIRCUIT FROM BRANCH\\RAINBOW ORDERS\\" + jtfSONo.getText().trim() + "\\PADR Release\\Final PADR Release 1.pdf";

    // Create a reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("K:\\DCIN_TER\\DCIN_EPU2\\CIRCUIT FROM BRANCH\\RAINBOW ORDERS\\" + jtfSONo.getText().trim() + "\\PADR Release\\Final PADR Release.pdf");

    // Create a stamper
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));

    // Loop over the pages and add a footer to each page
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
          Collection<Rectangle2D> rectangles = find(reader, 300, 100, n, stamper); // minimum width & height of a rectangle

          Iterator itr = rectangles.iterator();

          while(itr.hasNext())
          {
                 System.out.println(itr.next());
          }

          if(!(rectangles.isEmpty()) && (rectangles.size() != 0))
          {
                 Rectangle2D best = null;

                 double bestDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;

                 Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(200, 400);  

                 float x = 0, y = 0;

                 for(Rectangle2D rectangle: rectangles)
                 {
                       double distance = distance(rectangle, point);

                       if(distance < bestDist)
                       {
                              best = rectangle;

                              bestDist = distance;

                              x = (float) best.getX();

                              y = (float) best.getY();

                              int left = (int) best.getMinX();

                              int right = (int) best.getMaxX();

                              int top = (int) best.getMaxY();

                              int bottom = (int) best.getMinY();

                              System.out.println("x : " + x);
                              System.out.println("y : " + y);
                              System.out.println("left : " + left);
                              System.out.println("right : " + right);
                              System.out.println("top : " + top);
                              System.out.println("bottom : " + bottom);

                       }
                }

                getFooterTable(i, n).writeSelectedRows(0, -1, x, y, stamper.getOverContent(i)); // 0, -1 indicates 1st row, 1st column upto last row and last column
        }

        else
             getFooterTable(i, n).writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 94, 140, stamper.getOverContent(i)); // bottom left corner
   }

   // Close the stamper
   stamper.close();

   // Close the reader
   reader.close();

   public Collection<Rectangle2D> find(PdfReader reader, float minWidth, float minHeight, int page, PdfStamper stamper) throws IOException
   {
         Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox(page);

         Rectangle2D crop = new Rectangle2D.Float(cropBox.getLeft(), cropBox.getBottom(), cropBox.getWidth(), cropBox.getHeight());

         FreeSpaceFinder finder = new FreeSpaceFinder(crop, minWidth, minHeight);

         PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

         parser.processContent(page, finder);

         System.out.println("finder.freeSpaces : " + finder.freeSpaces);

         return finder.freeSpaces;
    }

    // Create a table with page X of Y, @param x the page number, @param y the total number of pages, @return a table that can be used as footer
   public static PdfPTable getFooterTable(int x, int y)
   {
         java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

         String month = sdf.format(date);
         System.out.println("Month : " + month);

         PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

         table.setTotalWidth(120);
         table.setLockedWidth(true);

         table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthTop(1f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthLeft(1f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthRight(1f);

         table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

         Font font1 = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);

         table.addCell(new Phrase("CONTROLLED COPY", font1));

         table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthLeft(1f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthRight(1f);

         table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

         Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED);

         table.addCell(new Phrase(month, font));

         table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColorBottom(BaseColor.BLUE);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthLeft(1f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthRight(1f);
         table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidthBottom(1f);

         table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

         table.addCell(new Phrase("BLR DESIGN DEPT.", font1));

         return table;
   }
```

Comment: iText does not offer that functionality out of the box. Depending of what kind of content you want to evade, though, you might consider either rendering the page to an image and looking for white spots in the image or doing text extraction with a strategy that tries to find locations without text.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the reply. i shall try text extraction first, but if the pages arfe scanned ones, then i will have to try the other one that you have mentioned.

Comment: could you please give examples for both with explanation?

Comment: I don't have any code for that lying around. Do you have any question on specific problems you came across when trying to implement these tasks?

Comment: Hi, since the program that you have written returns a collection, how can I select one from the collection and add or create the stamp there?????? Please guide me..........

Comment: In your `for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` loop you do `Collection<Rectangle2D> rectangles = find(reader, 300, 100, n, stamper)`. You surely meant `i`, not `n` there. This explains the dependency of the result on the number of pages.

Comment: superb, a simple mistake tat led to all these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My other answer focuses on the original question, i.e. how to find free space with given minimum dimensions on a page.*

*Since that answer had been written, the OP provided code trying to make use of that original answer.*

*This answer deals with that code.*

The code has a number of shortcoming.

1. **The choice of free space on a page depends on the number of pages in the document.**

   The reason for this is to be found at the start of the loop over the pages:

   ```
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {
       Collection<Rectangle2D> rectangles = find(reader, 300, 100, n, stamper);
       ...
   ```

   The OP surely meant `i`, not `n` there. The code as is always looks for free space on the last document page.
2. **The rectangles are lower than they should be.**

   The reason for this is to be found in the retrieval and use of the rectangle coordinates:

   ```
       x = (float) best.getX();
       y = (float) best.getY();
       ...
   getFooterTable(i, n).writeSelectedRows(0, -1, x, y, stamper.getOverContent(i));
   ```

   The `Rectangle2D` methods `getX` and `getY` return the coordinates of the *lower* left rectangle corner; the `PdfPTable` methods `writeSelectedRows`, on the other hand, require the *upper* left rectangle corner. Thus, `getMaxY` should be used instead of `getY`.

Comment: Hi,  works like a charm now....... :):):) thanks much......... a million thanks, got to learn lot from you....... great..........

Answer (score 4):

> is there any method by which I can read each page and if there is no text in that part add the stamp else search for nearest available free space, just like what a density scanner does?

iText does not offer that functionality out of the box. Depending of what kind of content you want to evade, though, you might consider either rendering the page to an image and looking for white spots in the image or doing text extraction with a strategy that tries to find locations without text.

The first alternative, analyzing a rendered version of the page, would be the focus of a separate question as an image processing library would have to be chosen first.

There are a number of situations, though, in which that first alternative is not the best way to go. E.g. if you only want to evade text but not necessarily graphics (like watermarks), or if you also want to evade invisible text (which usually can be marked in a PDF viewer and, therefore, interfere with your addition).

The second alternative (using text and image extraction abilities of iText) can be the more appropriate approach in such situations.

Here a sample `RenderListener` for such a task:

```
public class FreeSpaceFinder implements RenderListener
{
    //
    // constructors
    //
    public FreeSpaceFinder(Rectangle2D initialBox, float minWidth, float minHeight)
    {
        this(Collections.singleton(initialBox), minWidth, minHeight);
    }

    public FreeSpaceFinder(Collection<Rectangle2D> initialBoxes, float minWidth, float minHeight)
    {
        this.minWidth = minWidth;
        this.minHeight = minHeight;

        freeSpaces = initialBoxes;
    }

    //
    // RenderListener implementation
    //
    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        Rectangle2D usedSpace = renderInfo.getAscentLine().getBoundingRectange();
        usedSpace.add(renderInfo.getDescentLine().getBoundingRectange());
        remove(usedSpace);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        Matrix imageMatrix = renderInfo.getImageCTM();

        Vector image00 = rect00.cross(imageMatrix);
        Vector image01 = rect01.cross(imageMatrix);
        Vector image10 = rect10.cross(imageMatrix);
        Vector image11 = rect11.cross(imageMatrix);

        Rectangle2D usedSpace = new Rectangle2D.Float(image00.get(Vector.I1), image00.get(Vector.I2), 0, 0);
        usedSpace.add(image01.get(Vector.I1), image01.get(Vector.I2));
        usedSpace.add(image10.get(Vector.I1), image10.get(Vector.I2));
        usedSpace.add(image11.get(Vector.I1), image11.get(Vector.I2));

        remove(usedSpace);
    }

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() { }

    @Override
    public void endTextBlock() { }

    //
    // helpers
    //
    void remove(Rectangle2D usedSpace)
    {
        final double minX = usedSpace.getMinX();
        final double maxX = usedSpace.getMaxX();
        final double minY = usedSpace.getMinY();
        final double maxY = usedSpace.getMaxY();

        final Collection<Rectangle2D> newFreeSpaces = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();

        for (Rectangle2D freeSpace: freeSpaces)
        {
            final Collection<Rectangle2D> newFragments = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
            if (freeSpace.intersectsLine(minX, minY, maxX, minY))
                newFragments.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(freeSpace.getMinX(), freeSpace.getMinY(), freeSpace.getWidth(), minY-freeSpace.getMinY()));
            if (freeSpace.intersectsLine(minX, maxY, maxX, maxY))
                newFragments.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(freeSpace.getMinX(), maxY, freeSpace.getWidth(), freeSpace.getMaxY() - maxY));
            if (freeSpace.intersectsLine(minX, minY, minX, maxY))
                newFragments.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(freeSpace.getMinX(), freeSpace.getMinY(), minX - freeSpace.getMinX(), freeSpace.getHeight()));
            if (freeSpace.intersectsLine(maxX, minY, maxX, maxY))
                newFragments.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(maxX, freeSpace.getMinY(), freeSpace.getMaxX() - maxX, freeSpace.getHeight()));
            if (newFragments.isEmpty())
            {
                add(newFreeSpaces, freeSpace);
            }
            else
            {
                for (Rectangle2D fragment: newFragments)
                {
                    if (fragment.getHeight() >= minHeight && fragment.getWidth() >= minWidth)
                    {
                        add(newFreeSpaces, fragment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        freeSpaces = newFreeSpaces;
    }

    void add(Collection<Rectangle2D> rectangles, Rectangle2D addition)
    {
        final Collection<Rectangle2D> toRemove = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
        boolean isContained = false;
        for (Rectangle2D rectangle: rectangles)
        {
            if (rectangle.contains(addition))
            {
                isContained = true;
                break;
            }
            if (addition.contains(rectangle))
                toRemove.add(rectangle);
        }
        rectangles.removeAll(toRemove);
        if (!isContained)
            rectangles.add(addition);
    }

    //
    // members
    //
    public Collection<Rectangle2D> freeSpaces = null;
    final float minWidth;
    final float minHeight;

    final static Vector rect00 = new Vector(0, 0, 1);
    final static Vector rect01 = new Vector(0, 1, 1);
    final static Vector rect10 = new Vector(1, 0, 1);
    final static Vector rect11 = new Vector(1, 1, 1);
}
```

Using this `FreeSpaceFinder` you can find empty areas with given minimum dimensions in a method like this:

```
public Collection<Rectangle2D> find(PdfReader reader, float minWidth, float minHeight, int page) throws IOException
{
    Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox(page);
    Rectangle2D crop = new Rectangle2D.Float(cropBox.getLeft(), cropBox.getBottom(), cropBox.getWidth(), cropBox.getHeight());
    FreeSpaceFinder finder = new FreeSpaceFinder(crop, minWidth, minHeight);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    parser.processContent(page, finder);
    return finder.freeSpaces;
}
```

For your task you now have to choose from the returned rectangles the one which suits you best.

Beware, this code still may have to be tuned to your requirements:

- It ignores clip paths, rendering modes, colors, and covering objects. Thus, it considers all text and all bitmap images, whether they are actually visible or not.
- It does not consider vector graphics (because the iText parser package does not consider them).
- It is not very optimized.

Applied to this PDF page:

[image: Sample Invoice]

with minimum width 200 and height 50, you get these rectangles:

```
x       y       w       h
000,000 000,000 595,000 056,423
000,000 074,423 595,000 168,681
000,000 267,304 314,508 088,751
000,000 503,933 351,932 068,665
164,296 583,598 430,704 082,800
220,803 583,598 374,197 096,474
220,803 583,598 234,197 107,825
000,000 700,423 455,000 102,396
000,000 700,423 267,632 141,577
361,348 782,372 233,652 059,628
```

or, more visually, here as rectangles on the page:

[image: Sample Invoice with free rectangles at least 200x50 in size marked]

The paper plane is a vector graphic and, therefore, ignored.

Of course you could also change the PDF rendering code to not draw stuff you want to ignore and to visibly draw originally invisible stuff which you want to ignore, and then use bitmap image analysis nonetheless...

**EDIT**

In his comments the OP asked how to find the rectangle in the rectangle collection returned by `find` which is nearest to a given point.

First of all there not necessarily is *the* nearest rectangle, there may be multiple.

That been said, one can choose *a* nearest rectangle as follows:

First one needs to calculate a distance between point and rectangle, e.g.:

```
double distance(Rectangle2D rectangle, Point2D point)
{
    double x = point.getX();
    double y = point.getY();
    double left = rectangle.getMinX();
    double right = rectangle.getMaxX();
    double top = rectangle.getMaxY();
    double bottom = rectangle.getMinY();

    if (x < left) // point left of rect
    {
        if (y < bottom) // and below
            return Point2D.distance(x, y, left, bottom);
        if (y > top) // and top
            return Point2D.distance(x, y, left, top);
        return left - x;
    }
    if (x > right) // point right of rect
    {
        if (y < bottom) // and below
            return Point2D.distance(x, y, right, bottom);
        if (y > top) // and top
            return Point2D.distance(x, y, right, top);
        return x - right;
    }
    if (y < bottom) // and below
        return bottom - y;
    if (y > top) // and top
        return y - top;
    return 0;
}
```

Using this distance measurement one can select a nearest rectangle using code like this for a `Collection<Rectangle2D> rectangles` and a `Point2D point`:

```
Rectangle2D best = null;
double bestDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;

for (Rectangle2D rectangle: rectangles)
{
    double distance = distance(rectangle, point);
    if (distance < bestDist)
    {
        best = rectangle;
        bestDist = distance;
    }
}
```

After this `best` contains a best rectangle.

For the sample document used above, this method returns the colored rectangles for the page corners and left and right centers:

[image: Sample Invoice with free rectangles at least 200x50 in size marked and best rectangles filled]

**EDIT TWO**

Since iText 5.5.6, the `RenderListener` interface has been extended as `ExtRenderListener` to also be signaled about Path construction and path drawing operations. Thus, the `FreeSpaceFinder` above could also be extended to handle paths:

```
//
// Additional ExtRenderListener methods
//
@Override
public void modifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    List<Vector> points = new ArrayList<Vector>();
    if (renderInfo.getOperation() == PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT)
    {
        float x = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(0);
        float y = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(1);
        float w = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(2);
        float h = renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(3);
        points.add(new Vector(x, y, 1));
        points.add(new Vector(x+w, y, 1));
        points.add(new Vector(x, y+h, 1));
        points.add(new Vector(x+w, y+h, 1));
    }
    else if (renderInfo.getSegmentData() != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < renderInfo.getSegmentData().size()-1; i+=2)
        {
            points.add(new Vector(renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(i), renderInfo.getSegmentData().get(i+1), 1));
        }
    }

    for (Vector point: points)
    {
        point = point.cross(renderInfo.getCtm());
        Rectangle2D.Float pointRectangle = new Rectangle2D.Float(point.get(Vector.I1), point.get(Vector.I2), 0, 0);
        if (currentPathRectangle == null)
            currentPathRectangle = pointRectangle;
        else
            currentPathRectangle.add(pointRectangle);
    }
}

@Override
public Path renderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    if (renderInfo.getOperation() != PathPaintingRenderInfo.NO_OP)
        remove(currentPathRectangle);
    currentPathRectangle = null;

    return null;
}

@Override
public void clipPath(int rule)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

Rectangle2D.Float currentPathRectangle = null;
```

> *([FreeSpaceFinderExt.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/FreeSpaceFinderExt.java))*

Using this class the result above is improved to

[image: Sample Invoice with free rectangles at least 200x50 in size marked and best rectangles filled, extended render listener]

As you see the paper plane and the table background colorations now also are taken into account.

Comment: hi,  one small doubt as I am new to java and itext, how should I add the stamp ( as in my program)? How should I call the code written by you? Since it gives so many free space, how should I tell the program where to insert the stamp?

Comment: Hi,  since the program that you have written returns a collection, how can I select one from the collection and add or create the stamp there?????? Please guide me..........

Comment: *how should I add the stamp ( as in my program)?* - whenever you have a PDF and want to apply changes to it like adding stamps or filling in forms, you should use the iText PdfStamper class.

Comment: *how can I select one from the collection* - that depends on the requirements you have. As you currently stamp in the upper left corner, you might want to use the rectangle which is nearest  to that corner. Or you might want the rectangle nearest to any corner... Thus, check the requirements of your project and choose accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I am using PdfStamper in the program and adding the stamp to the upper-left corner. But, how do i filter out the rectangles nearest to that area? How do I code it?

Comment: I am calling the code that you have written like this: find(reader, 200, 50, n) inside a for loop, looping over each page. Now, this will return a collection. How will I filter it and tell the code to take only the botton left corner?

Comment: *How will I filter it and tell the code to take only the botton left corner?* - You iterate through the collection and test each individual rectangle. If it contains that point, you can use that corner, otherwise you have to choose a different position. Which one depends on the requirements of your task.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I am using this to iterate over the Collection: `Iterator itr = finder.freeSpaces.iterator();   while(itr.hasNext()  {  }  `  When I print the elements, I get `[com.itextpdf.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=0.0,width=595.0,height=842.0]]`  . How do I tell that if x is this and y is this or x falls in between this and y falls in between this, then add the stamp here... in the program?  Please guide me, I am pretty new to IText and java, still learning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63909/discussion-between-user1416631-and-mkl).

Comment: for all documents or all pages in a document it gives the same result as above..............

Comment: Rectangle2D has a method contains(double x, double y), Cf. The [API documentation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html).

Comment: hey, thanks for your patience and reply..... Please see my edited program on the top and lert me know where i am wrong. & how can I get the X & Y. I am using contains, but, don't know how to get the x-y

Comment: *how to get the x-y* - how to get **which** x,y?

Comment: Hi,  the ones that we pass into the contains function......... Please see my edited program and let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: Have you meanwhile defined where the stamp shall go? Because your test points depend on that definition.

Comment: Hi,  In the program, I have commented out 2 lines calling getFooterTable function. I need to add the stamp at 0, -1, 94, 140

Comment: *I need to add the stamp at 0, -1, 94, 140* - if you need to stamp there, why do you check at all? Or asked the other way around, where do you need to stamp if stamping at that position would cover text? What are your requirements then?

Comment: Hi, Sorry as it was weekend, coud not reply back. If this position i.e., 0, -1, 94, 140 has no text then add the stamp here else in the nearest available free space the stamps has to be added. So, here, how do I check these in the contains function? What should I pass onto contains function?

Comment: Hi, I had not seen your edited post..... One clarification, please let me know what is the "**point**" in double distance = distance(rectangle, point); ? It is not defined anywhere. Is it related to 0, -1, 94, 140 that I had mentioned. This may sound silly question.

Comment: I have defined point as Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(94, 140);

Comment: *I have defined point as Point2D.Double* - that is ok. As mentioned in my answer, `point` is a `Point2D`; whether it is a `Point2D.Double` or `Point2D.Float`, does not matter.

Comment: Ok, thanks, let me give it a try. I am learning new things from you... Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: In my programs, there is one line to add the stamp, i.e., getFooterTable(i, n).writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 94, 140, stamper.getOverContent(i)); (in a for loop). How do I write the rectangles co-ordinates (got from your program) into this?

Comment: How do I get the co-ordinates of the "**best**" rextangle of type rectangle2d? Rectangle has getLeft(), etc functions, but Rectangle2D does not have any functions to find the coordinates.

Comment: *Rectangle2D does not have any functions to find the coordinates* - What makes you think so? If you look at the code above you will see methods `getMinX()`, `getMaxX()`, `getMinY()`, and `getMaxY()` used to query the coordinates of the `Rectangle2D`. Any decent IDE would have offered those methods to you. Alternatively you can lookup iText sources or API documentations.

Comment: One doubt, if I want to search for the best rectangles in a page and not one point (here we are searching for best rectangle nearest to one point) and insert the stamp in one of the rectangles, is it possible?

Comment: How do you define *best rectangles in a page*?

Comment: The ones that are easily visible (as i scroll down from page to page) and fit the text in the stamp properly. Usually people tend to see the start or end of the page

Comment: So essentially the rectangle nearest to either the top or the bottom of the page. That is merely a slight variation of the *rectangle nearest to a given point*, simply calculate `distance` as the smaller of the distances of the rectangle to the top and bottom of the page.

Comment: I had already tried it, it adds the stamp to the same place, either bottom left corner or top left corner. Sometimes, only half of the stamp is visible (when it comes to bottom left corner). What to do in such cases?

Comment: Can this be possible - If a bigger (more wide and height) rectangle is found, insert the stamp there or if multiple rectangles of same size are available, choose one among them and insert............

Comment: That would be: Search a biggest rectangle size in the list. The problem is how to measure bigness. E.g. you want to place a 20x10 stamp and have rectangles with sizes 40x30, 100x20, and 20x100. Area-wise the latter two are the largest, but the first one has the largest minimum margin.

Comment: *only half of the stamp is visible* - that means the `minWidth` and `minHeight` you used were too small.

Comment: When I place it in bottom left corner, half the stamp goues below the page (not visible). My stamp size is (or the PdfPTable into which I write the Stamp contents) width - 120, height of each cell is 20 (total 3 cells - 120X60). The minWidth is 300, minHeight is 100. Point2D is Point2D.Double(200, 400). For this, the stamp is inserted in the bottom left corner of each page & as I said, half of the stamp is not visible. I think, the minWidth & minHeight is more than sufficient to accomodate the stamp. Please let me know where am I going wrong. Shall I post my edited code?\

Comment: Please share your result PDF for analysis.

Comment: Hi, i will share, and the code when I run for Pdf with 4 pages, it inserts stamp to bottom left corner and only half of the stamp is visible. but, with the same coordinates when I run the code, for Pdf with 1 page, inserts the stamp somewhere else. Why is this happening? Two different Results for the same co-ordinates but, with different number of pages.

Comment: When I print the values of X & Y, I displays 3 values: 1st - x = 145, y = 556; 2nd - x = 277, y = 556; and 3rd - x = 295, y = 556. But, it selects only the 1st set of X & Y and inserts the stamp.

Comment: I have added the 2 resulting files. As you can see, for the same co-ordinates of Point2D as 200, 400 and minWidth and minHeight of rectangle as 300X100, for a pdf with 1 page the result is different from that for a pdf with 4 pages.

Comment: Please share your result PDF for analysis, not just screenshots of it.