# How to determine remaining space on a pdf page with itext

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I need to sign PDF documents, but I need to know where to place the signature on the document to scan and determine if there's available space on the last page or if I need to create a new page to put the signature and whether I need to sign it multiple times: [image: Screenshot example].

I'm using itext to manipulate PDF documents that I am using:

```java
availableSpace = stamper.getWriter().getVerticalPosition(true); // to determine the available space
```

And this is how I draw the rectangle:

```java
    Rectangle dimensiones = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(numberOfPages);
    PdfContentByte dr = stamper.getOverContent(numberOfPages);

    float right = dimensiones.getBorderWidthRight() * (-1);
    float left = dimensiones.getBorderWidthLeft() * (-1);
    float width = dimensiones.getWidth();
    float height = dimensiones.getHeight();
    log.debug("bottom<<"+dimensiones.getBorderWidthBottom());


    width = width - (right+left+80);
    //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 36, 559, 806);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(80, 36, width, (height-availableSpace));
    rect.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
    dr.rectangle(rect);
```

But some PDFs get more `availableSpace` than their respective height, so the rectangle doesn't appear correctly.

What I want is to determine the space left on the last page to add the signature, and add pages if the signature doesn't have enough space.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might want to use the `FreeSpaceFinder` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503289/1729265).