# Fetch rectangle (line segments)co ordinates from pdf using itextpdf

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to get the line segments co ordinates total & line segments should come. I want to read the pdf table co ordinates so that I can fetch the text inside the co ordinates? I am getting only 6 line segments. What about the 7 line segment?

I am using this program to read the line segments from tables(rectangle)

[iText : image on PDF only if the position is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240121/itext-image-on-pdf-only-if-the-position-is-blank)

```
output is :


 50 50  150 50
150 50  150 150
150 150 50  150
150 50  200 50
200 50  200 150
200 150 150 150
```

[image: Rectangle is as in figure]

Comment: You don't share your PDF, so how can we tell...

Comment: I have shared the screenshot of the pdf that contains rectangle.

Comment: You don't share your PDF, so how can we tell... (a screenshot does not help because it only shows the *result* of drawing, not the exact drawing instructions)

Comment: In pdf i just have this rectangle.

Comment: Which instructions exactly are used in the pdf content stream to draw this divided rectangle?

Comment: PageSize ps = pdfWdoc.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle.");
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfWdoc.getPdfDocument().getFirstPage());
        //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(ps.getWidth() - 90, ps.getHeight() - 100, 50, 50);
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 50);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(150, 50, 100, 50);canvas.rectangle(rect1);
       canvas.rectangle(rect2);
        canvas.stroke();
        pdfWdoc.close();

Comment: Ah, so you create that PDF yourself. That of course also allows reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yes my intention is to read the co ordinates of the line segments that make up the table.After that i have to read the data in the table with merge and split cells.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is that iText reports a *rectangle drawing instruction* as subpath containing three explicit lines (bottom, right, top) and sets its `Closed` property implying the fourth line (left):

```
public void rectangle(float x, float y, float w, float h) {
    moveTo(x, y);
    lineTo(x + w, y);
    lineTo(x + w, y + h);
    lineTo(x, y + h);
    closeSubpath();
}
```

*(`com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Path.rectangle(float, float, float, float)`)*

The `FreeSpaceFinder` in the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240467/1729265), though, only considers the explicit subpath segments, not the implied one. Thus, for your two rectangles you only get 6 lines instead of the expected 8 lines.

To also get implied closing lines for each `Subpath subpath`, you have to check whether `subpath.isClosed()`, and if it is, you have to determine the end point of the last `IShape segment` in `subpath.getSegments()` and the start point of the first `IShape segment` and add a line connecting those points.

Comment: But if i have complex table consisting of merge and split cells then it will be very complex to read it everytime and to check whether subpath is closed or not.

Comment: *"But if i have complex table consisting of merge and split cells then it will be very complex to read it everytime and to check whether subpath is closed or not."* - Why? You  only reference that other question and don't provide your own code. Thus, I have to assume that your code in that regard is very similar to the referenced code. But in that referenced code the loops over the subpaths and their segments is well capsuled. If you add the code dealing with closed paths right there, there is hardly any complexity increase.