# Get Free Space Location around particular location in PDFBox tool in Java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to place dynamic text based on text in PDF. I have read each page in PDF, find text in PDF and place corresponding matched text surrounding place of it. But the text is placed over the another text or Box or line. I need to place dynamic matched text on Free Space. But i couldn't find method to find free space in surrounding place of PDF text using Java PDFbox. 
Please find our code in the below.

```
package com.mycompany.pdfboxsample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;



/**
 *
 * @author Gayathri.R
 */
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try{
        PDDocument document = null; 
        document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Gayathri\\Smartacrf\\sample\\ItextSample\\oldcrf20.pdf")); 
        List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        Iterator iter = pages.iterator(); 
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();
            Map<String,PDXObject> pageImages = resources.getXObjects();
            if (pageImages != null) { 
            Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
            while (imageIter.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) imageIter.next();
                PDXObjectForm image = (PDXObjectForm) pageImages.get(key);
                COSBase cosObject = image.getCOSObject();
                System.out.println("Finded");
                float lowerleftx =image.getBBox().getLowerLeftX();
                float upperleftx =image.getBBox().getLowerLeftY();
                float lowerlefty =image.getBBox().getUpperRightX();
                float upperlefty =image.getBBox().getUpperRightY();
                float width =image.getBBox().getWidth();
                float height =image.getBBox().getHeight();

            }
            }
        }

    }   
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody working on this type of task? If yes, please share your thoughts

Comment: I have followed this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464324/how-can-i-can-insert-an-image-or-stamp-on-a-pdf-where-there-is-free-space-availa?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa . It was very helpful me. But free space is identified by itext using above URL.
Anybody know how to achieve this in PDFbox?