# c#, check area of pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to enter a text to existing pdf (in top or bottom of the page) in c#. 
I need to make sure that I dont overwrite any visible text or image.

Is there any way I could check an area in pdf if it contains text, image, control etc? I understand it will not be 100% accurate

Comment: please attach an example picture and some actually usefull informations so we can help you better with your problem

Comment: Denis what is wrong with the question? You dont understand what I want to do?

Comment: it is absolutly unclear what situation your are in. After reading your questions 3 times i still cant tell what you want to do and it looks like at least 3 other people had the same issue

Comment: You tagged your question with `itext`, which means that you already know that there is a library to do something like that, you just don't know exactly _how_ to do it. Is that correct? Please rephrase your question in that way, to get better answers. And explain what you have already tried yourself. Thank you!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26503289/1729265) demonstrates how to find empty areas using iText and Java. It shouldn't be too difficult to port the code there to iText for .Net and C#.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a full PDF consumer at the very least, because the only way to find out where the marks are on the page is to parse (and possibly render) the PDF.

There are complications which you haven't covered (possibly they have not occurred to you); what do you consider to be the area of the PDF file ? The MediaBox ? CropBox, TrimBox, ArtBox, BleedBox ? What if the PDF file contains, for example, a rectangular fill with white which covers the page ? What about a /Separation space called /White ? is that white (it generally gets rendered that way on the output) or not ? And yes, this is a widely used ink in the T-shirt printing industry amongst others.

To me the simplest solution would seem to be to use a tool which will give you the BoundingBox of marks on the page. I know the Ghostscript bbox device can do this, I imagine there are other tools which can do so. But note (for Ghostscript at least); if there are any marks in white (whatever the colour space), these are considered as marking the page and will be counted into the bbox.

The same tool ought to be able to give the size of the various Boxes in the PDF file (you'd need the pdf_info.ps program for Ghostscript to get this, currently). You can then quickly calculate which areas are unmarked.

But 'unmarked' isn't the same things as 'white'. If you want to not count areas which are painted in 'white' then the problem becomes greater. You really need to render the content and then look at each image sample in the output to see if its white or not, recording the maxima and minima of the x and y co-ordinates to determine the 'non-white' area of the page.

This is because there are complications like transfer functions, transparency blending, colour management, and image masking, any or all of which might cause an area which is marked with a non-white colour to be rendered white (a transparency SMask for example) or an area marked with white to be rendered non-white (eg a transfer function).

Your question is unclear because you haven't defined whether any of these issues are important to you, and how you want to treat them.