# Add text to last page of existing PDF with java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, openpdf

I know there are many suggestions how to resolve problems with edition existing PDF, but among all of those, I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I need to add information about file acceptance ("Document accepted by Tom Smith, 2020-01-01" - possible multiple acceptations) to the last page of the PDF. I need to determine if page is filled or is there enough space for my text.
I wanted to find position (y) of the last element on the last page of the pdf to check it against page size. If the page is full I'm going to add a new page and then add new text.
I have no idea how to resolve this. I tried looking for answers with iText and PDFBOX, but there are no satisfying resolutions.

Comment: In respect to iText have you tried the `FreeSpaceFinderExt` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26503289/1729265)? It allows you to find arbitrary unused areas; for your task you might want to use the bottommost one.

Comment: please share your existing code with iText. There are methods to achieve what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Raster Image based approach:

Render the last page of the pdf to a bitmap image with any library you are comfortable with (Ghostscript?). 72 dpi should be enough for your purpose.

Then you can use any image processing library like openCV and check rectangular areas starting from the bottom up, if pixel exist. openCV is very fast with the CountNonZero() function.

You can also find any large white zone that is anywhere in the Image, not just at the bottom. This link could be your starting point.

https://answers.opencv.org/question/72939/how-to-find-biggest-white-zone-in-an-scanned-image/