# How do I get the size of Header, Footer size of PDF file in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, size

I trying to get the **sizes of header, footer and side white-spaces of PDF files using Java**. E.g. File1 has a footer size of 20px, File2 has Footer size of 15px. Is there any way to determine this? Till now I have worked with *iText PDFReader*. It returns me the sizes of MediaBox and CropBox. I am not able to translate these values into comparable data. Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: do you mean the page margins?

Comment: In general the information you ask for are not explicitly present in a PDF.

Comment: @jhamon, yes, I mean the same.

Comment: @mkl is there a way to get the these information, in a different way?

Comment: If those margin areas are completely empty, you can determine the bounding box of the actual page contents as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417899/1729265). But beware, some PDF generators start a page by filling its whole area with a white rectangle. The solution in the referenced answer will consider such a background rectangle content, too! And actual header, footer, or margin texts will of course also count.