# How can I add source PDF content to destination PDF using iText 7 without losing the header and footer?

Tags: pdf, itext7

I am using iText 7. I have two PDF files. The source PDF has some content. The destination PDF has header and footer. I have a requirement to add the content from source PDF to destination PDF in the middle of the page without overlapping header and footer of the destination PDF. What should the code be?

Below is my code and attached document is the screenshot of the source PDF file which needs to be embedded in the *final.pdf* file:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgram;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfFormXObject;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Style;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.SolidBorder;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.HorizontalAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.UnitValue;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment;

public class TestPdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(Paths.get("Output").toAbsolutePath()+"/final.pdf"))).setSmartMode(true);
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
            pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
            String fonts[] = {Paths.get("fonts").toAbsolutePath() + "/TREBUC.TTF", Paths.get("fonts").toAbsolutePath() + "/TREBUCBD.TTF", Paths.get("fonts").toAbsolutePath() + "/TREBUCBI.TTF",Paths.get("fonts").toAbsolutePath() + "/TREBUCIT.TTF"};
            FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
            Map<String, PdfFont> pdfFontMap = new HashMap();
            for (String font : fonts) {
                FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font);
                if(font.endsWith("TREBUC.TTF")) {
                    pdfFontMap.put("NORMAL", PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true));
                } else if(font.endsWith("TREBUCBD.TTF")) {
                    pdfFontMap.put("BOLD", PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true));
                } else if(font.endsWith("TREBUCBI.TTF")) {
                    pdfFontMap.put("BOLD_ITALIC", PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true));
                } else if(font.endsWith("TREBUCIT.TTF")) {
                    pdfFontMap.put("ITALIC", PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true));
                }

                fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
            }
            TestPdf testPdf = new TestPdf();
            NormalPageHeader headerHandler = testPdf.new NormalPageHeader(Paths.get("images").toAbsolutePath() + "\\logo.png", pdfFontMap);
            pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, headerHandler);
            PageEndEvent pageEndEvent = testPdf.new PageEndEvent(Paths.get("images").toAbsolutePath() + "\\FooterLineExternal.png" ,pdfFontMap);
            pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, pageEndEvent);
            Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

            doc.getPageEffectiveArea(PageSize.A4.rotate());
            Table imageTable = new Table(1);
            imageTable.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            imageTable.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Title");
            paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
            cell.add(paragraph);
            cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setPaddingTop(50);
            imageTable.addCell(cell);
            doc.add(imageTable);
            doc.close();
            System.out.println("Converted to PDF Succesfully >>> convertedSvg_"+uuid+".pdf");
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Error Occured while converting to PDF = " + e.getMessage());
         }
    }


    class NormalPageHeader implements IEventHandler {

        String header;
        Map<String, PdfFont> font;
        public NormalPageHeader(String header, Map<String, PdfFont> font) {
            this.header = header;
            this.font = font;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            //Retrieve document and
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
            PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
            canvas.setFontSize(10f);
            Table table = new Table(3);
            table.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
            Cell leftCell = new Cell();
            leftCell.setFont(font.get("NORMAL"));
            leftCell.setPaddingTop(15);
            leftCell.setPaddingLeft(20);
            leftCell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            leftCell.setBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
            leftCell.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(33.3f));
            Text userLabel = new Text("Username: ");
            userLabel.setBold();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(userLabel);
            Cell middleCell = new Cell();
            middleCell.setFont(font.get("NORMAL"));
            middleCell.setPaddingTop(15);
            middleCell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            middleCell.setBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
            middleCell.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(33.3f));
            paragraph = new Paragraph("Main Header");
            paragraph.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            paragraph.setBold();
            paragraph.setFontSize(12);
            middleCell.add(paragraph);
            String programString = "Sample header";
            paragraph = new Paragraph(programString);
            paragraph.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            paragraph.setBold();
            paragraph.setFontSize(10);
            middleCell.add(paragraph);

            table.addCell(middleCell);
            Cell rightCell = new Cell();
            rightCell.setFont(font.get("NORMAL"));
            rightCell.setPaddingTop(20);
            rightCell.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(33.3f));
            rightCell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
            rightCell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            rightCell.setBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
            rightCell.setPaddingRight(20);
            //Write text at position
            Image img;
            try {
                img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(header));
                img.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                Style style = new Style();
                style.setWidth(91);
                style.setHeight(25);

                 img.addStyle(style);
                 rightCell.add(img);
                 table.addCell(rightCell);
                 table.setMarginLeft(15);
                 table.setMarginRight(15);
                 canvas.add(table);
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class PageEndEvent implements IEventHandler {

         protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
         protected float side = 20;
         protected float x = 300;
         protected float y = 10;
         protected float space = 4.5f;
         private String bar;
         protected float descent = 3;
         Map<String, PdfFont> font;
         public PageEndEvent(String bar, Map<String, PdfFont> font) {
             this.bar = bar;
             this.font = font;
             placeholder =new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));
         }

         @Override
         public void handleEvent(Event event) {
             Table table = new Table(3);
             table.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
             table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
             Cell confCell = new Cell();
             confCell.setFont(font.get("NORMAL"));
             confCell.setPaddingTop(15);
             confCell.setPaddingLeft(20);
             confCell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
             confCell.setBorderBottom(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
             confCell.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
             PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
             PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
             PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
             Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
             PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
             page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
             Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
             Image img;
             try {
                 img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(bar));
                 img.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
                 Style style = new Style();
                 style.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
                 style.setHeight(50);
                 img.addStyle(style);
                 Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("Test: Confidential");
                 p.setFont(font.get("NORMAL"));
                 p.setFontSize(8);
                 p.setFontColor(com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants.GRAY);
                 canvas.showTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.CENTER);
                 pdfCanvas.addXObject(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
                 pdfCanvas.release();
             }
             catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }

         public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf) {

             Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);

             canvas.showTextAligned(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages()),
                                    0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
         }

     }

}
```

Comment: Is the content in the source pdf already positioned so that it would not overlap the header and footer of that stationary pdf? If it is, the requirement is fairly easy to implement. If not, how do you expect the content to be changed to fit the available area? Does shifting it a bit suffice? Or shall it be scaled? Or do you actually think about re-flowing the existing layout to match the available space?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I have edited my question by adding the code and the screenshot of the source PDF. The source PDF is not positioned. I expect the content to be in between header and footer in the final PDF. Can you please have a look at it ?

Comment: *"I expect the content to be in between header and footer in the final PDF"* - does it suffice to merely move to the right position? Or is scaling also necessary?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be moved to the right position along with scaling !

Comment: Ok. Which section if the page should be put into the free area? As your name appears to be added all over the page, an automatic content detection would indicate the whole page while you probably only want the drawing and the letters at its corners. Furthermore, how can the area to put the content into be determined? If there also is your name printed all over it (or some background graphic is), automatic free space determination may fail.

Comment: Kindly Ignore my name which is appearing all over the document. It is not required to be added. In Actual, as per the image shared the source pdf will have one page with one graph in it. This PDF content needs to be put into the destination PDF along with header and footer.

Comment: @mkl  Hi, can you please let me know if you have any update ?

Comment: I'm not yet in office, and yesterday was a holiday here.

Comment: Ok. Whenver you have time, Please have a look at it. Thank you for the support !

Comment: Ok, I'm looking into this right now. One clarification request, though, in your question you originally said and still say *"the destination PDF has header and footer"* between which to add the source PDF content, but in your code the page has content, the `imageTable`. In the original context one could simply fit the copied part of the source page into the `PageEffectiveArea` of that page. In the new context one cannot simply do so but has to consider the place your table takes, too. Which is the actual context, the former one (and your `imageTable` just being some filler) or the latter one?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. ImageTable was just added to be a filler. In Addition, I tried to convert the source PDF to image and add it to the destination PDF using Itext. But the image quality looked bad. Especially , In case of PDF with graphs, the image will not be effective. So, I was trying out possibilities to embed the source PDF as it is without converting it to image !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, some words on the iText architecture behind some constructs you use:

When you use a `Document` instance to add content to a document that iText shall layout automatically, the assumption is that the area where iText can layout stuff is the whole page minus the page margins.

Thus, if you add further page material via other channels than the `Document`, e.g. like you do in your `NormalPageHeader headerHandler` and your `PageEndEvent pageEndEvent`, it is *your responsibility* to do so *outside the layout area* explained above, i.e. in the margin areas. (Unless that additional material is background stuff, like a water sign...)

For this you should set the margins large enough to guarantee that your further material is in the margins. By default the page margins are set to 36pt on each side of the page which usually is enough for a single line header or footer but not really for multi-line ones.

In your code you create a header which requires at least some 52pt plus a bit to prevent the content iText will layout from touching the header line.

Keeping that in mind it is pretty straight forward to insert a given `PdfPage sourcePage` into your page:

```java
...
NormalPageHeader headerHandler = testPdf.new NormalPageHeader(Paths.get("images").toAbsolutePath() + "\\logo.png", pdfFontMap);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, headerHandler);
PageEndEvent pageEndEvent = testPdf.new PageEndEvent(Paths.get("images").toAbsolutePath() + "\\FooterLineExternal.png" ,pdfFontMap);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, pageEndEvent);

Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.setTopMargin(55);
PdfFormXObject xobject = sourcePage.copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
Rectangle xobjectBoundaryBox = xobject.getBBox().toRectangle();
xobject.getPdfObject().put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(new float[] {1, 0, 0, 1, -xobjectBoundaryBox.getLeft(), -xobjectBoundaryBox.getBottom()}));
Image image = new Image(xobject);
image.setAutoScale(true);
doc.add(image);

doc.close();
...
```

*(excerpt from [InsertInSpace](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/merge/InsertInSpace.java#L131) helper `insertIntoNithinTestFile`)*

---

If you use the original source page as is, the above code will insert it including all margin space. If you don't want this but instead cut that space of, you can proceed as follows to determine the actual bounding box of the page content, reduce the page to that box, and forward it to the method `insertIntoNithinTestFile` above, assuming page 1 of `PdfDocument pdfDocument` shall be processed:

```java
PdfDocumentContentParser contentParser = new PdfDocumentContentParser(pdfDocument);
MarginFinder strategy = contentParser.processContent(1, new MarginFinder());

PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(1);
page.setCropBox(strategy.getBoundingBox());
page.setMediaBox(strategy.getBoundingBox());
insertIntoNithinTestFile(page, "test-InsertIntoNithinTestFile.pdf");
```

*([InsertInSpace](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/merge/InsertInSpace.java#L76) test `testInsertSimpleTestPdf`)*

The `MarginFinder` is a port of the iText5 [`MarginFinder`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/MarginFinder.java) to iText 7:

```java
public class MarginFinder implements IEventListener {
    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
        return boundingBox != null ? boundingBox.clone() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (data instanceof ImageRenderInfo) {
            ImageRenderInfo imageData = (ImageRenderInfo) data;
            Matrix ctm = imageData.getImageCtm();
            for (Vector unitCorner : UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS) {
                Vector corner = unitCorner.cross(ctm);
                addToBoundingBox(new Rectangle(corner.get(Vector.I1), corner.get(Vector.I2), 0, 0));
            }
        } else if (data instanceof TextRenderInfo) {
            TextRenderInfo textRenderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data;
            addToBoundingBox(textRenderInfo.getAscentLine().getBoundingRectangle());
            addToBoundingBox(textRenderInfo.getDescentLine().getBoundingRectangle());
        } else if (data instanceof PathRenderInfo) {
            PathRenderInfo renderInfo = (PathRenderInfo) data;
            if (renderInfo.getOperation() != PathRenderInfo.NO_OP)
            {
                Matrix ctm = renderInfo.getCtm();
                Path path = renderInfo.getPath();
                for (Subpath subpath : path.getSubpaths())
                {
                    for (Point point2d : subpath.getPiecewiseLinearApproximation())
                    {
                        Vector vector = new Vector((float)point2d.getX(), (float)point2d.getY(), 1);
                        vector = vector.cross(ctm);
                        addToBoundingBox(new Rectangle(vector.get(Vector.I1), vector.get(Vector.I2), 0, 0));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (data != null) {
            logger.fine(String.format("Ignored %s event, class %s.", type, data.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        } else {
            logger.fine(String.format("Ignored %s event with null data.", type));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return null;
    }

    void addToBoundingBox(Rectangle rectangle) {
        if (boundingBox == null)
            boundingBox = rectangle.clone();
        else
            boundingBox = Rectangle.getCommonRectangle(boundingBox, rectangle);
    }

    Rectangle boundingBox = null;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MarginFinder.class.getName());
    static List<Vector> UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS = Arrays.asList(new Vector(0,0,1), new Vector(1,0,1), new Vector(1,1,1), new Vector(0,1,1));
}
```

*([MarginFinder.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/merge/MarginFinder.java))*

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your valuable time to respond. I will check your solution and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, I copied your solution but then when I ran i got this strange error "com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action" at this line "PdfFormXObject xobject = sourcePage.copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);"  Did you happen to get this error during testing ?

Comment: No. You appear to already have closed the source document at that time. It mustn't be closed then to allow copying from it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I am closing the document at the end. I have posted the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574450/itext-7-1-6-document-was-closed-it-is-impossible-to-execute-action . Can you please have a look at it ?

Comment: *"I am closing the document at the end."* - No, you clearly close it much earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support ! Issue got fixed :)

Comment: One quick question. Does the MarginFinder.java class adds a margin to the left and right side when the source PDF content is being copied to destination PDF ?

Comment: The `MarginFinder` does not add an extra margin. But it also is not explicitly intelligent, it includes all content, not only the visible content. E.g. if there is an initial instruction to fill the whole page with white color, the whole page is considered used by it.

Comment: Hi, Hope you are doing good. Can you please let me know how can I use the same code provided by you to add the source PDF content to the end of the Destination PDF or in a new page of destination PDF ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"to the end of the Destination PDF"* in particular in contrast to *"in a new page of destination PDF"*?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I meant, i have a destination PDF and I have 2 PDF pages. How Can i add headers and footers to these PDF pages and add them to the Destination PDF as new pages ?

Comment: How about creating those two pages in a new PDF and thereafter copying the other pages before them? To discuss this or other options in detail, please make that a separate stack overflow question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I created a separate stack overflow question here for one HTML containing svg element and converting it to PDF. I have shared the complete code here  . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027844/how-can-i-convert-html-with-svg-content-to-pdf-using-itext-pdf-api