# Java iText There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I have the following method [that scales an image to A4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505060/java-itext-scale-document-to-a4/63562347#63562347)

```
   void scale(PdfDocument pdfDocument, Rectangle pageSize, Rectangle pageBodySize) {
    int n = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);

        MarginFinder marginFinder = new MarginFinder();
        PdfCanvasProcessor pdfCanvasProcessor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(marginFinder);
        pdfCanvasProcessor.processPageContent(page);
        Rectangle boundingBox = marginFinder.getBoundingBox();
        if (boundingBox == null || boundingBox.getWidth() == 0 || boundingBox.getHeight() == 0) {
            System.err.printf("Cannot scale page %d contents with bounding box %s\n", i, boundingBox);
            continue;
        } else {
            // Scale and move content into A4 with margin
            double scale = 0, xDiff = 0, yDiff = 0;
            double xScale = pageBodySize.getWidth() / boundingBox.getWidth();
            double yScale = pageBodySize.getHeight() / boundingBox.getHeight();
            if (xScale < yScale) {
                yDiff = boundingBox.getHeight() * (yScale / xScale - 1) / 2;
                scale = xScale;
            } else {
                xDiff = boundingBox.getWidth() * (xScale / yScale - 1) / 2;
                scale = yScale;
            }

            AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(pageBodySize.getLeft() + xDiff, pageBodySize.getBottom() + yDiff);
            transform.scale(scale, scale);
            transform.translate(-boundingBox.getLeft(), -boundingBox.getBottom());

            new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument)
                    .concatMatrix(transform);

        }
        page.setMediaBox(pageSize);
        page.setCropBox(pageSize);
    }
}
```

This method is invoked/called in this snippet :

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream mergedPdfStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument mergedPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(mergedPdfStream));

    for (PdfDocument doc : pdfDocuments) {
        int n = doc.getNumberOfPages();
      
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       
            PdfPage page = doc.getPage(i).copyTo(mergedPdf);
            mergedPdf.addPage(page);
          
        }
        Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4;
        Rectangle pageBodySize = pageSize.clone().applyMargins(72, 72, 72, 72, false);
        scale(doc, pageSize, pageBodySize);
    }

   

    mergedPdf.close();
```

However , when it performs this code at the end

```
 new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument)
                .concatMatrix(transform);
```

It throws an PDF Exception There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects:

```
 com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects.
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.makeIndirect(PdfObject.java:228) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.makeIndirect(PdfObject.java:248) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.newContentStream(PdfPage.java:1186) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.newContentStreamBefore(PdfPage.java:244) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
```

How can I fix this problem? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
scale(doc, pageSize, pageBodySize);
```

for each `PdfDocument doc` in `pdfDocuments`. So *after copying the pages* to `mergedPdf` you try to scale the pages *in your source documents*. You cannot scale the pages in your source `PdfDocument` instances as they are opened read-only (i.e. only with a `PdfReader`, without a `PdfWriter`), and doing so *after* copying also doesn't make sense as you surely want to scale what's in the result `mergedPdf`, not in the sources.

Thus, move the block

```
Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4;
Rectangle pageBodySize = pageSize.clone().applyMargins(72, 72, 72, 72, false);
scale(doc, pageSize, pageBodySize);
```

out of the outer `for` loop body, after it, and replace the last line by

```
scale(mergedPdf, pageSize, pageBodySize);
```

to scale the resulting merged PDF.